# Does linux do outer ip fragmentation

Tags: linux-kernel

I am looking to understand if Linux has the capability to do fragmentation of the outgoing packets at inner IP or outer IP level?
I looked the source code in /net/ipv4/files in Linux kernel source, but do not find reference to the fragmentation level.
Or should I be looking at layer 2 level files where where the decision might be made based on MTU size?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a networking/TCP/IP theory question and not Linux related.

Comment: Linux does implement fragmentation. Why is it not a Linux question?! The concept is network related but configuration and setting is linux specific :). Thanks

Comment: What am I missing?  I don't see a question about networking theory; I see a question about the Linux implementation of the IP protocol.  That's on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Linux could do fragmentation, but like incoming packets, the kernel try hard not to do fragmentation on first place (e.g. with *path MTU discovery* before to sending, receiving data).

You can see e.g. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_output.c
function `ip_do_fragment`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like Linux does not have the concept of fragmentation at outer ip level. I.e it will fragment packets at inner ip level, encrypt and send the packets out ( in IPSEC environment)